# Create a Script bundle from multiple locations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

Let's assume our app is offline, i.e. we can't use 3rd party CDNs thus we're creating our own.
I'd like to host all of the vendor scripts in a separate (Parent) web app and then include them in the bundles in several other MVC Apps.

e.g.

- `http://localhost/parentWeb/Scripts/jquery.js`
- `http://localhost/parentWeb/Scripts/jquery-ui.js`
- `http://localhost/parentWeb/Scripts/globalize.js`

I'd like to include in the ASP.NET MVC App Website located in:  `http://localhost/parentWeb/childWeb`

i.e. do something like this:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle(
        "~/bundles/VendorScripts",
        "http://localhost/parentWeb/Scripts/jquery.js",
        "http://localhost/parentWeb/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
        "http://localhost/parentWeb/Scripts/globalize.js"));
```

...which of course isn't currently possible. Is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 14):

You can't bundle external resources. If you think about it, it makes sense why you can't. It would require the bundler to actually download the resource and save it to the filesystem before it could work with it, and of course do it all asynchronously with some sort of fallback if the external resource couldn't be reached. And, then, it would have to do this on *every page load* because it can't check for lastmod (and therefore, know whether it actually needs to rebundle or not) without fetching the resource first.

If you use a CDN resource, the bundler merely prints the URL directly to the page; it doesn't make any modifications. Even then, it only lets you create a "bundle" of just that one URL, because 1) it wouldn't make sense to bundle multiple CDN resources since that would defeat the purpose of a CDN and 2) the bundle only exists in this scenario to provide a fallback if the CDN resource is unavailable. Otherwise, you would be served just as well by just hardcoding it to the page and not worrying about setting up a bundle at all.

Comment: While you can't bundle external resources (your points are very correct) ScriptBundle actually has support for CDNs. This blog post explains everything very well http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx

Comment: @BryanRayner: Not sure what the conflict is. I never said bundling doesn't have CDN support. Quite the opposite, actually, as I mention using CDNs with script bundles. However, like I say in my answer above, the bundler doesn't actually *do* anything with the CDN resource. It just drops a static script tag on the page to the CDN file. It won't minify/combine it with other scripts or CSS files.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I have to agree - You never said bundling doesn't have CDN support. When I initially read your answer, "You can't bundle external resources" seemed to suggest that ScriptBundles could not be used to serve external resources to the client.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old topic, but I came here looking for an actual way to bundle CDN resources. From [@Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt)'s answer, I understood it wasn't possible.

If you're wondering, I am working on optimizing an an existing project according to [Google's Web Performance Best Practises](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html) which gives a low score when there are multiple script tags and a higher one when all scripts are bundled into a single script reference.

I needed a way to bundle all the CDN script resources as well as local resources in order. I worked on this [github repo](https://github.com/mykeels/CdnBundle), which solved my problem.

With it, you build a bundle with a list of bundles, each containing a reference to the cdn resource, local resource to save to, and a Boolean indicating whether or not you want the bundle to be minified.

```
List<Bundle> jsBundles = new List<Bundle>();
jsBundles.Add(new Bundle("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js", @"~/jquery.min.js", Bundle.BundleType.JavaScript, false));
jsBundles.Add(new Bundle("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js", @"~/jquery-ui.min.js", Bundle.BundleType.JavaScript, false));
jsBundles.Add(new Bundle(@"~/my-local-script.js", Bundle.BundleType.JavaScript, true));
```

To place on the page, you use

```
@jsBundles.Load();
```

This will process all bundles in the list, downloading content for bundles that have not been downloaded in the last 24 hours *(It updates every 24 hours or when the web application restarts)*. All content downloaded will be placed in local files *(where specified)*.

All content will be combined into the final result which will be spooled into the page in a script tag *(or link tag for CSS)*.

The Load function also accepts a local File URL for the final script/css content. If specified, a  tag with a src to the relative path for that local file will be given instead. E.g.

```
@jsBundles.Load("~/js/all-my-scripts.js");
```

The above statement will return something like:

```
<script src="~/js/all-my-scripts.js"></script>
```

An async attribute may be added to the script tag if the second parameter of the Load function is provided.

It also works on css cdn resources too. E.g.

```
List<Bundle> cssBundles = new List<Bundle>();
cssBundles.Add(new Bundle("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css", @"~/jquery.ui.css", Bundle.BundleType.CSS, false));
cssBundles.Add(new Bundle(@"~/css/my-local-style.css", Bundle.BundleType.CSS, true));


@cssBundles.Load("~/css/all-my-styles.css");
```

This is for the benefit of those, who like me, came in here looking for a way to actually bundle CDN resources.

Comment: Clever solution, but doesn't this defeat the purpose of using a CDN? Web clients will have to download the full bundled CDN scripts from your server because they won't have it in their caches. With true CDN script links, the point is that there's a high chance that your web client already has the script file cached since many other sites link to the same CDN URL.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a solution, which has nothing to do with CDN. Basically, granted the `childWeb` is hosted in the `parentWeb`'s subdirectory, the following bundle configuration in the `childWeb` apps picks the file from the parentWeb and bundles them as usual:

```
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle(
        "~/bundles/VendorScripts").Include(
        "~/../Scripts/jquery.js",
        "~/../Scripts/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
        "~/../Scripts/globalize.js"));
```

the important bit being: `~/../`, which takes you one level up from the root location.

Comment: so with your solution where is store cdn path in that code i have the same issue i need also load multiple css in bundle using cdn so please can you let me know how can do that?

Comment: You are the OP so I guess you are entitled to write what you want in response but the title is in regards to multiple CDN locations and this is not a solution for that question

Comment: hey @HostMyBus , you are right. I have un-accepted my answer to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

To use ScriptBundles with CDN resources, you need to use the overloaded constructor. Unfortunately you need to specify multiple `ScriptBundle`s per file.

Here's a great blog post explaining things:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx

And here's a code snippet:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bundleNameHere", "//cdn.host.path/to/file");
// Path to the version of the file on your server (in case the CDN fails)
bundle.Include("~/../Scripts/path/to/file");
// JS expression to run, to test if CDN delivered the file or not
bundle.CdnFallbackExpression = "window.ValueYouExpectToBeTruthy";

bundles.Add(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of bundle is reduce the traffic of your web server where your web application hosted. using bundle the script files will not load in parallel. this is needed when you are using your local files.

but in case of cdn the files will load from cdn server so you don't have need to make bundle for cdn. you need bundle for local files only