# MVC Bundling outside link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I save whatever is in this link and use it for my MVC bundling?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css">
```

```cs
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
                    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                             "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js")); 
}
```

Comment: you need to download the file and put it in the solution

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad Thank you, that what I have no clue how to do that. But ur answer help me change my question.

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248612/create-a-script-bundle-from-multiple-locations

Answer (score 0):

If you have a link like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css">
```

Then go to https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css

1. Right click the page then Save As - it should be a `.cs` file
2. After saving it, just copy it to your MVC Project inside `Content` folder.
3. Bundle it:

```cs
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/blitzer.css")); 

// This is what I added, I named my file blitzer when saving it
```